# Redirecting to a new page

Tags: php, javascript

I have defined a function in which i want to open a page on a new window. The function has following code:

```
echo"<script>window.location.href='http://localhost/paymentsystem/views/payment.php?id=".$id."'</script>" ;
```

Right now its opening the page on the same window.

I want to know how can i open this page on a new tab?

Regards,

Pankaj

Comment: Is there a reason you're sending a script to the client to do a redirect when the page loads? Why not redirect server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
window.open("yourSite.html","plain","width=470,height=452");
```

instead of window.location.href

Answer (score 2):

if you prefer to use html to open new window then you have to use below

```
       <a href="example.html" target="_blank">link text</a>
```

and to implement it in javascript you have to try below

echo"window.open('http://localhost/paymentsystem/views/payment.php?id=".$id."')" ;

I hope this will help you..

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
<a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">Click here</a>
```

for a simpler solution, although I believe the 'target' attribute will be deprecated soon.